# Navigation Bar Buttons Displacing to the Right

Tags: html, css

my navigation bar is shifting to the right because of some fa icons. Is there some solution in css that wont cause the middle three buttons to shift? My plan is to have the "projects" button in the middle and the the two fa icons on the left. Also, any other css tips would help since I'm new and it's slowing me down quite a bit.

Relevant html:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #1F3037;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hide;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EDF8FD;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.nav a.home {
  border-left: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.nav a.proj {
  border-left: 3px solid #347C98;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.nav a.cont {
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
}

.bio {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.fancy {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="[cut out]" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
  <a href="[cut out]" class="fa fa-github"></a><a href="" class="home">Home</a><a href="" class="proj">Projects</a><a href="" class="cont">Contact</a>
</div>
```

result:
[image: Home, Projects, and Contact slightly shifted to the right.]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired behavior by using separate divs for each of your favicons, as well as the home, projects and contact buttons.

The fa class is split into fa1 and fa2 to account for the margin on the left of the GitHub button, and `position: absolute` is used for each.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #1F3037;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hide;
  z-index: 21;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EDF8FD;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.home {
  border-left: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.proj {
  border-left: 3px solid #347C98;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.cont {
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  width: 8%;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.fa1 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EDF8FD;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

.fa2 {
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EDF8FD;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#;" class="fa1">L</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#;" class="fa2">G</a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <a href="#;" class="home">Home</a>
  <a href="#;" class="proj">Projects</a>
  <a href="#;" class="cont">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use flex and remove a lot of css here.  I showed how to move the "Contacts" to the right also but if not, remove the `margin-left:auto;` which does that

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
  background-color: #1F3037;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hide;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EDF8FD;
  border-right: 3px solid #347C98;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #347C98;
}

.nav .proj {
  align-self: center;
}

.nav a.cont {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-github">&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="proj">Projects</a>
  <a href="#" class="cont">Contact</a>
</div>
```